# Advanced Reporting Question

Tags: reporting, custom-object, report-builder

We have a need to show how many of our Accounts have 3 or more Licenses. I am having a hard time getting this into a report.

We have a License &  Registration object that has all of our application names with a maintenance status field, and these are tied to accounts.

1. Need to find out how many accounts have > 3 licenses with maintenance = Y
2. % of Accounts with > 3 licenses with maintenance = Y

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the relationship between Licence and Account a MD relationship?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I will clarify that in an edit.

Comment: Start by adding a roll-up summary field on Account that counts the number of Licenses with maintenance = Y, and go from there.

Comment: Exactly my idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a rollup summary field in Accounts for the number of licences.
- Create a formula field say 'licencecount' to calculate the number of licences returning 1 for > 3 and returning 0 for <= 3 with type Y.
- Create a Summary Report with reporttype Accounts
- In the report, summarize on licencecount
- In the report, create a formula field to display the number of total records in the grand total
- In the report, create a formula field to display the percentage in the grant total (RowCount / Account.licencecount__c:SUM)

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I can write apex all day but report building is how they bring me down... lol

Comment: Can you tell me what the formula field to calculate the % would look like?

Comment: Right.. I will update my post for that

Comment: See updates in post. Have fun!